# Reporting Linux System Adminstration Data via SharePoint

Tags: integration, linux

I have an automated script running on a Linux system that collects information such as user load, disk usage, etc. and emails it to my personal account. I would like to have this data automatically imported and published on our SharePoint site to be viewed by other system administrators. Ideally, I'd like some kind of visual display in graphs, charts, etc. but this may be beyond SharePoint capabilities.

Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to install any third party applications to parse or publish the data and need to use built-in SharePoint functionality. Does anyone have any ideas how I could implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Una option without development is send an email to SharePoint (to a list).

See point 2 (Email enable a SharePoint List or Library) in [Five out-of-the-box ways to get Email into SharePoint](https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/five-out-of-the-box-ways-to-get-email-into-sharepoint/)